# Want to post one to many relation data with json MVC3

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, jquery, razor

**Client**

```
public class ClientModelData
{
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public IList<int> LocationID { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddClient(ClientModelData client)
    {
        Client _client = new Client()
        {
            //ClientCode=client.ClientCode,
            ClientName = client.ClientName,
            Phone = client.Phone,
            Ext = client.Ext,
            Address = client.Address,
            CreatedBy = 1,
            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
            ModifiedBy = 1,
            ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
            ModifiedIP = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
        };
        db.Clients.Add(_client);
        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            string error = string.Empty;
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    error += string.Format("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, 
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);

            return Json(new
            {
                status = false,
                message = "Unable to update information for selected client, please contact administrator. For detail <a class='errordetail'>click here</a>",
                exception = error
            });
        }
        return Json(_client);
    }
```

I have a checkbox list:

```
<ul class="locations">
                                @foreach (var item in Model.Locations)
                                {
                                    <li>
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="checkbox" id="chkLocations" name="chkLocations" 
                                            value="@item.LocationID" />
                                            @item.LocationTitle</label>
                                    </li>
                                }
                            </ul>
```

** The Json object contains the values: **

```
var allVals = [];
            $('#chkLocations:checked').each(function () {
                allVals.push($(this).val());
            });
            var dataPacket = {
                ClientName: $("#txtClientName").val(),
                Phone: $("#txtPhone").val(),
                Ext: $("#txtExt").val(),
                Address: $("#txtAddress").val(),
                LocationID: allVals
            };
```

Now the problem occurs, when I give the checkbox:checked items it don't populate the ModelData Entity **Location** property

Image:

> [http://tinypic.com/r/eapem9/6](http://tinypic.com/r/4l0bqr/6)

**Issue Comes Up POSTING form...JQuery AJAX**

Image:

> http://tinypic.com/r/4l0bqr/6

Comment: <form name="frmAddClient" id="frmAddClient" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
...
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Save Informaiton</button>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you haven't shown us how are you calling the controller action. You could try sending them as a JSON request which allows you to POST arbitrarily complex objects to your controller actions:

```
var allVals = [];
$('#chkLocations:checked').each(function () {
    allVals.push($(this).val());
});
var dataPacket = {
    ClientName: $("#txtClientName").val(),
    Phone: $("#txtPhone").val(),
    Ext: $("#txtExt").val(),
    Address: $("#txtAddress").val(),
    LocationID: allVals
};
```

and then:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("AddClient", "SomeController")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ client: dataPacket }),
    success: function(result) {
        // ... handle the result
    }
});
```

Notice the usage of the `JSON.stringify` method which is natively built into modern browsers to send the request as a JSON string. We are also setting the request content type header to `application/json` in order for the application to use the proper JSON value provider and parse this request to your model.

Comment: this is how I am calling the controller action  url: "/client/AddClient"

Comment: That's wrong. You seem to have hardcoded it. You should never hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application. You should always use url helpers to build them. Otherwise your application will stop working when you publish it in a virtual directory in IIS. If this is in a separate javascript file then you cannot directly use url helpers inside this file but you could build the url in your view using url helpers and then use it in your javascript file.

Comment: when I put JSON.stringify(dataPacket), controller parametter class all values becomes null: http://tinypic.com/r/2l8vt46/6

Comment: Try like this: `JSON.stringify({ client: dataPacket })`. This assumes that your action argument is called `client`. Also try debugging the AJAX request with FireBug. What exactly is sent to your controller action?

Comment: ok i will take care of this. Please let me know how can i post my values I am stucked :(

Comment: this is posted to ajax: {"client":{"ClientName":"HBL","Phone":"dsfasdf","Ext":"324","Address":"awedasdasd","LocationID":["1","2","3"]}}

Comment: This seems fine and it should map correctly to your controller action argument. Where are you executing this request? Could it be in a form submit handler or an anchor click handler in which you forgot to cancel the default action by returning `false`?

Comment: yes its in the form submit handler, on form submission i am making an ajax request with json object.

Comment: And did you return false at the end of this submit handler? Also how is this form created? Did you use `Html.BeginForm` or `Ajax.BeginForm`?

Comment: No, I have used usuall <form> but without action, and there is a submit button within it.

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments section. It is unreadable. Update your original question and include all relevant information.

Comment: what possible case, its not populating the properties?

Comment: I don't know. You haven't shown your code. I cannot be guessing.